# Make the sharing links more readable

Tags: support, feature-request, design

I have been in situations where I exactly not sure whether the question is an exact duplicate of some other question. In that case, I don't want to rise a flag because I am not sure about that so what I will do in this case is that I will just go to the question that I think might be the duplicate and have some answers and copy the share link from the question.

Now I come back to the newly asked question and paste that link as a comment somewhat like this

> This might help you -> [The question title goes here ?](https://stackoverflow.com)

Notice about the formatting here in order to do this I need to go back to that question twice cause I want to copy both title and the share link. I feel this as somewhat more readable than this

> This might help you -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/644566/6465456

So In order to fix this how it will be if we make the current share button itself to produce us the formatted text with both title and link so that I can just paste it. Or A new button somewhat like `share with the title` which does the same job?

Comment: The share button can’t output formatted text because the majority of the internet doesn’t use markdown, and the sharing button needs to work for _everywhere else_. The real issue is with comments not inserting the title automatically.

Comment: [I have a userscript](https://github.com/PurpleMagick/so_userscript-share-questions-as-markdown/blob/master/src/share-markdown-link.user.js) which allows sharing questions as markdown. It adds a new button "share markdown" to questions (and questions only) which takes the title and formats it as a markdown link using the shortlink for the question. I also remove the user ID from the link. I made it mostly for my own use but feel free to use it and suggest new ideas.